# ayuda con varios DIV y creacion

Tags: javascript, html, css

Mi código es el siguiente y funciona perfectamente, ademas de eso hay más div, pero quiero agregar un botón que se llama como "Agregar nueva habitación" y cuando se le presione quiero que se cree otra más en el body similar al código que esta presente ¿Es posible realizar eso? Si es así ¿Más o menos como pudiera elaborarlo?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sig(){
    var array = new Array(" Disponible ", " Ocupado ", " Mantenimiento ",);
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if(document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value == array[i]) {
        var indice = (i + 1 == array.length) ? 0 : i + 1;
        document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value = array[indice];
        localStorage.setItem("estado", array[indice]);
        break;
       }
    }
   }
   window.onload=function()
  {

  if(localStorage.getItem("estado") != null) {
    estado =localStorage.getItem("estado");         
    document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value = estado;            
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="text-align:center">
<div class="span2">
<div class="well well-small">
  <h4>Habitación 1</h4>
  <input id="Fmbtn" type="button" value=" Disponible " onclick="sig()" />
  <a href="habitacion1.php"><small>Ver detalles</small></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: estas usando localStorage? o no se puede tomar en cuenta localstorage para tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear con createElement y luego darle una clase de css para que adquiera tu estilo que quieras ponerlo.

```js
var i = 0;

function sig() {

  var array = new Array(" Disponible ", " Ocupado ", " Mantenimiento ");
  if (i + 1 < array.length) {
    i++;
    crearDivs(array[i], array);
  } else {
    i = 0;
    crearDivs(array[i], array);
  }
}

function crearDivs(nameDiv, array) {
  let divNuevo = document.createElement('div');
  divNuevo.classList.add('divs');
  divNuevo.innerHTML = nameDiv;
  
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(divNuevo);
  document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value = array[i];
}
```

```css
.divs {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="text-align:center">
  <div class="span2">
    <div class="well well-small">
      <h4>Habitación 1
      </h4>
      <input id="Fmbtn" type="button" value=" Disponible " onclick="sig()" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio a la perfeción, pero otra cosa, sabes que ya tengo otros div creado y en esos divd esta un boton, el div cuando apreto en el boton se crea bien ¿pero existe la posibilidad que en ese div tambien aparezca el boton que ya tengo en los otros div configurado?

Comment: @EduardoOrtiz hace otra pregunta con tu nueva duda y un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable

Comment: ¿Esta bien que haya respondido en mi misma pregunta? ¿O decias que creara una nueva del todo? porque formule aca la nueva

Comment: @EduardoOrtiz una nueva del todo porfavor

Comment: Listo, gracias por tu ayuda, si quieres te puedes pasar para que veas, gracias de nuevo!!!

Answer (score 1):

desde la funcion de JS donde pones el boton a la escucha creas los elementos algo asi...

```
 let nuevoElemento = document.createElement('li');
```

investiga sobre `document.createElement('etiqueta que quieres crear');`

y asi crearas todo.

espero te srirva y la marques como solucion By: JJ

Answer (score 1):

Bueno seria algo similar, viendo el codigo que puse primero y este, tengo varios div que es el de abajo, el numero 12 es el ultimo, todos tienen el boton disponible que lo que hace es cambiar a ocupado-mantenimiento. Le agregue lo que me has puesto, que es la ultima linea del codigo otro boton afuera de todos los div que ya tengo, cuando le doy añadir habitacion me sale la otra habitacion al lado de la numero 12 (Yo edite el codigo que me pasaste entonces sale habitacion 13,14,15 etc y asi) pero el div en blanco, ¿se puede hacer que cuando le de añadir y salga habitacion 13 le salga automaticamente el boton que tienen los demas?

```
<div class="span2">
<div class="well well-small">
<h4 >Habitación 12</h4>
<input id="este12" type="button" value=" Disponible " onclick="sig12()" />
<br>
<a href="habitacion1.php"><small>Alquilar</small></a>
</div>
</div>
```

```
<center><input id="crear1" type="button" value=" Añadir habitación " 
onclick="crear()" /></center>
```